# Firefox does not display commercial site when using the proxy server (JMeter recording)

Tags: firefox, jmeter

Steps I have done to (successfully) record a test plan to test jmeter.apache.org:
- Configure the JMeter HTTP proxy server (port: 8080)
- Set up Firefox to use the proxy server
- Configure the proxy natively on my PC (window 10)

But when I do the same to record another test plan to test a commercial site, like Walmart or Barnes and Noble. Firefox does not display the sites and shows message

> The proxy server is refusing connections
>   Firefox is configured to use a proxy sever that is refusing connections.

When I set "No Proxy for Walmart.com" in Firefox Connection Setting, the site displays improperly (only text links show)
How could I got the commercial sites to display correctly when using proxy server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Firefox has its own mechanism for setting up proxy connectivity, it does not respect global proxy settings, check out the [latest Firefox documentation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/advanced-panel-settings-in-firefox#w_connection) to learn how it can be configured (I'm not providing instructions or screenshots as given browsers roll out new releases each few days it may change at any moment)
2. Browser **must** use JMeter's proxy if you want to record the traffic, otherwise JMeter may not be able to intercept the requests and convert them into [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers
3. If your website uses HTTPS protocol you will need to install JMeter's self-signed certificate in your browser so JMeter could decrypt and record HTTPS requests. See "HTTPS recording and certificates" chapter of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) User Manual entry for information on how to install the certificate for different browsers

Troubleshooting options:

- I would recommend always use [clean session](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/clear-your-browsing-history-and-other-personal-data) for recording, i.e. delete your browsing history, cookies, cache, etc. or use a brand [new Firefox profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) for recording.
- If above options don't resolve your issue you can consider an alternative option of recording a JMeter test - [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension), using it you don't need to setup proxies or install SSL certificates.